# Groups hiding sight. site reference logos

Tags: javascript, html

I have a reference page, but I want to edit it. I would like to separate them according to the working areas. For example technology health and so on. I'm doing a work for it but I'm usually interested in php these are things I haven't looked at in a very long time. I don't like JS and try not to use it unless I have to. my problem is that following a single id appear others trying to make it hidden. but it was so I can not help me how to call I do not know what to scan.

```js
function gizleGoster(ID) {
  var secilenID = document.getElementById(ID);
  if (secilenID.style.display == "none") {
    secilenID.style.display = "";
  } else {
    secilenID.style.display = "none";
  }
}
function tumu() {
  var secilenID = document.getElementById('health');
     secilenID.style.display = "";
     secilenID = document.getElementById('technology');
     secilenID.style.display = "";
     secilenID = document.getElementById('automotive');
     secilenID.style.display = "";
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="tumu()">All</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="gizleGoster('health')">Health</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="gizleGoster('technology')">Technology</a>
<a href="#" onclick="gizleGoster('automotive')">Automotive</a><br>

<br>
<br>
<div id="health">health</div><br>
<div id="technology">technology </div><br>
<div id="automotive">automotive</div><br>
<div id="health">health</div><br>
```

Comment: please tell your objective more briefly.

Comment: When I click on the health button, only the health-related ones may appear to hide the others. I click on technology, only the ones that are related to technology. click all to show all on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way it could be done. You may need to tweek this as required to get it to fit your use case. Please take note that I have also modified your HTML too.

```js
function getIndustries() {
    return document.getElementById('industries').getElementsByTagName("div");
}

function hideElement(element){
    element.style.display = "none";
}

function showElement(element) {
  element.style.display = "";
}

function tumu() {
  var industries = getIndustries();
  for(var industry of industries) {
    showElement(industry);
  }
}

function gizleGoster(ID) {
  var industries = getIndustries();
  for(var industry of industries) {
     if (industry.className === ID) {
        showElement(industry);
     }
    else {
        hideElement(industry);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" onclick="tumu()">All</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="gizleGoster('health')">Health</a> 
<a href="#" onclick="gizleGoster('technology')">Technology</a>
<a href="#" onclick="gizleGoster('automotive')">Automotive</a><br>

<br>
<br>
<div id="industries">
  <div class="health">health</div><br>
  <div class="technology">technology </div><br>
  <div class="automotive">automotive</div><br>
  <div class="health">health</div><br>
</div>  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much. I usually know that, but I forgot I didn't use it anytime soon.

Comment: No worries. If this helped to answer your question, please could you mark it as best answer. Thanks.